# Coding a Tumblr Theme - List posts as list or just a stack of divs?

Tags: html, semantics, tumblr

I'm in the process of coding my own Tumblr Theme.

Well I was wondering how should I list the posts? In the basic theme, (the one you get when you sign up) doesn't use list items (`<li>`). But I saw in another theme that it does use list items.

By the way, this is what I mean...

```
<div class="post-text"><div>
<div class="post-audio"><div>
...
```

or

```
<ul>
 <li class="post-text"></li>
...
</ul>
```

I'm confused on the way I should go - I want to go to the semantic way of doing it because the theme will be built in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tumblr you can code it anyway you like - either by using list items, divs, or in your case sections, asides and nav.

I've mostly built themes using divs, seeing as you might end up with a case where you use lists within your post descriptions; in which case you'll end up with lists in lists in lists. Of course this is perfectly valid (beats using tables!), but for posterity sake I don't like it very much.

If you want scope out some code of a tumblr theme I've built using HTML5, check out [Minimus](http://minimus.tumblr.com/) - a commercial theme I've got going at themeforest :)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build it semantically, go with the right element. In this case, if you're going to be doing it in HTML5, I'd think that you would use a different tag entirely - I'd think that an `<article>` tag, or a `<section>` tag would better fit here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your theme presents the posts as - are they separate divisions within the page, or are they a list of items for the user to browse over?